# Renaming and deleting a text file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to experiment with the whole idea of creating two text files then write to one of them, rename the second file with the first file and then deleting the first file. I have a school project where i need to apply this concept. So, before i actually applied the concept in my project, I tried to experiment with a rough code. Now, everything works fine except that the second file doesn't contain the data from the first file. How do i fix this problem?

This is my class which is called potpie:-

```
package project4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class potpie {

    PrintWriter out,cr;

    File file1 = new File("trial.txt");
    File file2 = new File("item.txt");

    public void createfile() throws IOException
    {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file1,true));

        out.println("User1" + "639755");

        cr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2,true));
        cr.close();
        out.close();
        file1.delete();
        file2.renameTo(file1);

}

}
```

I am getting blank output in my trial.txt file and i don't know where i made the mistake. Please help me out.

Comment: You are not writing anything to the second file, no wonder why it's empty

Comment: I recommend learning how to use a debugger such as the one in Eclipse. It will let you run your program step by step and figure out what's not correct.

Comment: You close the stream attached to the file without using it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your real intent was :

```
public class potpie {

    PrintWriter cr;

    File file1 = new File("trial.txt");
    File file2 = new File("item.txt");

    public void createfile() throws IOException
    {
        cr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2,true));

        cr.println("User1" + "639755");    

        cr.close();
        file1.delete();
        file2.renameTo(file1);

   }

}
```

What you are currently doing is renaming an empty file, so no wonder why the renamed file will be empty too. BTW, you are not using correctly the concept of attribute in your class, you should give a good thought to a better structure for your code.

Comment: :- Thank you very much. I dont have 15 reputation points. So, i cant upvote your answer yet. But thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it's helpful, but happy it helped you anyway, Bye :)

Answer (score 0):

You created blank file2. Then you wrote "User1" + "639755" to file1. Then deleted file1 and renamed file2 to file1. Obviously you get blank file1.

Comment: :- Thank for correcting me. My goal was to copy the contents in file1 to file2 and then deleting file1 and renaming file2 to file1. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to `file1`, then deleting it, then renaming `file2` (which you haven't written to) to `file1`. Perhaps you meant to delete the empty file and rename to it?

Comment: :- Thank for correcting me. My goal was to copy the contents in file1 to file2 and then deleting file1 and renaming file2 to file1. How can i do that?